# Stop user's executing JavaScript from console

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I've been mucking around creating a little multiplayer game using HTML5 technologies. I used Node.js and Socket.IO to manage server-side business.

My problem lies in users being able to enter in their own JavaScript through the Chrome console (and various other consoles im sure). For example, a user might enter this into the console:

```
socket.emit("new player", {user: username, x: localPlayer.getX(), y: localPlayer.getY()});
```

This would add a new player to the game. What is the best way I should go about stopping this? Is there a way I can catch these entries and simple deny them (followed by slapping the user around the face)? It would be also good if I could stop them editing things like the GUI by changing variables, eg:

```
gameStatus = "trolled lol troll client-side editing lol";
```

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: You can't.  You can never trust anything that comes from a client. You need to validate everything on the server.

Comment: @SLaks I think the user is asking how to distinguish requests sent to the server by his script and script written by someone into a console.

Comment: @Asad: Exactly.  That's totally impossible.

Comment: @SLaks So how would you correct the problem?

Comment: @Asad: The server needs to know what each client is allowed to do.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheating_in_online_games

Comment: Asad is right, could someone please give an example of how a server knows what to do? I need somebody to tell me how the server knows what each client is allowed and how it would go about determining if it's right or wrong.

Comment: @jskidd3 If you were to include a few more details (perhaps more code) about how the `new player` functionality works on the server and client side, someone might be able to help you come up with a concrete way to correct the problem.

Comment: @jskidd3: As the designer of the game, you should know what you want users to be allowed to do.  You just need to translate that into code.  For example, a user is probably not allowed to edit a different player.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## You cannot do that.

You can never trust anything that comes from a client.
Even if you could somehow affect the console from your page, an attacker could write his own web browser (read: fork Chromium) and bypass your restrictions.
Or the attacker could simply handcraft HTTP requests without any browser at all.

Instead, you need to validate everything on the server.
Whenever any client does something, the server needs to check whether that client is actually allowed to do that.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a little on how I would go about doing everything on the server? How would the server know when the client has entered a JavaScript command through the console?

Comment: @jskidd3: The whole point is that it is fundamentally impossible for the server know that.  \

Comment: So perhaps the best thing to do here would be learn a new language for creating games? :P

Comment: What I'm asking for is how is something validated on the server?

Comment: it does not depend on the language you use. Everything that runs on client side is subject to "hacking". Javascript/html is one of the easiest though as it is not even compiled. 

it is impossible to prevent that. Though you can reduce the risk. One method is to obfuscate your javascript code (make is difficult to read). That will discourage and make it harder to hack but i repeat it is impossible to stop them if they really want too.

Comment: You can also wrap all your code inside self-calling function and that way prevent any global access to your code. That makes it a little bit harder to hack your game.

Comment: @jskidd3: Your server eventually handles your game (at least I hope so), the client does something (i.e. moves), and the server receives that command and updates the database (or whatever permanent storage you have). When you do that updating, the server needs to make sure the move the player made is valid (i.e. moved only one block, and not to the other side of the map). That is called *validation*, you make sure the command you were given is *valid*. This process needs to be done for any sort of input arriving from the client. Do not trust anything the client says blindly.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ok thanks very much. One thing though, sort of stems back to the original question, let's say it's possible to change your level through simply editing a variable through console. Surely an event has to be fired for the server to be able to check whether the level is legitimate or not? There's something I'm missing here... is there some sort of listener to check if variables change? Or do I have the server checking each play every second to make sure they're the right level? Clearly the event is more efficient, but I don't know how to go about coding it like that.

Comment: @jskidd3: You can change the level through to the variable in JavaScript, sure, but that would mean nothing. Assuming the server only accepts level change through EXP change, and EXP change only through monster change, it wouldn't listen to what the client says about the level or the EXP, it would only listen the the client saying *I attacked a monster*, the rest of the calculation (damage, monster slaying, EXP gain and level gain). The client shouldn't have a say in this.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by SLaks, there's no way to prevent someone from hacking and it's even more true for a javascript/html client as it is easier. There are ways to discourage or make it harder though as i said in my comment. I am posting more suggestions

1. Obfuscate your javascript code
2. Use an encryption method and encrypt all your requests to your server before sending them using a key (make it hard to find the key)
3. decrypt your request on server side using same encryption method and key as in the javascript client.

Comment: None of these solve the problem that clients are fundamentally not secure.  You must validate with server-side logic; anything else is smoke and mirrors.

Comment: Yeah, and its wrong.  There is a way to prevent hacking, and its via server-side validation.

Comment: how can you validate that on server side?:

    socket.emit("new player", {user: username, x: localPlayer.getX(), y: localPlayer.getY()});

you can detect anormal movements on server side but at the end of the day, you can't prevent the client from making a fake request unless you restrict your game at client side (ex. allow one slot movement at a time but this cannot be applied to all games).

Comment: As i written in my answer, you can validate it. Just send a token with each message and check it on server side. For instance, when client first logs in you create a random token which will be passed to the client side on app start. Each message you send, should append that token, just make sure you encript it so no one knows the structure of your object and obviously the token value. Just validate the token sent by the client on server side and you know if you can trust it

Comment: @Dslayer - that won't work either. The OP is concerned about the threat posed by a clever user at the javascript console. That user can call the encryption routine (if its client side) and fabricate a message easy as pie. If the encryption is being done on the server then its even easier to send a fake message with the token. The method you present would protect against a 3rd party who is eavesdropping from fabricating the messages but not the legitimate end user / cheater.

Comment: @Dslayer like schmidlop said, if you are encrypting at client side, the end user can see your token and encryption algorithm: so he can forge his own message. (he has your random token and your algo)

Comment: yes he can have both, but just like any computer security it's about numbers. With this you filtered 99% of people trying to crack the system. With that you reduced a lot the number of abnormal movements you need to analyse from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

What we mean about  not trusting what comes from client side is doing exactly what you do when you create a form. You  usually  check post method, session, a  unique token  unrelated to  the meaningful data you are sending - usually a hidden text input created on the server side and checked when form is submited. search validating and sanitizing form. On top of this you should encript the data for sending so it won't be possible to rebuild the structure using the network tab on chrome or firebug or even a proper traffic analyser.